# CMake set file specific compilation option

Tags: c, gcc, cmake

I want to use specific compilation options for a specific file using the set_source_files_properties() command.

It looks like it is not working but I am not able to find what I do wrong.

I use the following commands to build my project:

```
cmake -B build
cmake --build build
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(my_project C)

set(target main.out)
add_executable(${target})
target_compile_options(${target} PRIVATE -Wall -Wextra)
target_include_directories(${target} PRIVATE .)
target_sources(${target} PRIVATE main.c)
set_source_files_properties(abc.h PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS -Werror)
```

main.c:

```
#include "abc.h"

int main(void) {
    return 0;
}
```

abc.h:

```
#ifndef ABC_H
#define ABC_H
typedef struct {
    int a;
};
#endif
```

If I run CMake, I get a warning:

```
./abc.h:3:1: warning: typedef requires a name [-Wmissing-declarations]
```

but I would expect an error because I set the -Werror compilation option to the file abc.h in which I get the warning.

Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Comment: The problem is that header files aren't compiled, thus compiler-flags on them won't be used.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CMake: how to set COMPILE\_FLAGS for header files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48162570/cmake-how-to-set-compile-flags-for-header-files). Indeed, headers are not compiled, per se, they are included in the compilation of **source** files. Hence, the CMake command is called `set_source_files_properties` . The answer to the linked question has a detailed explanation for what options you might have to approach this. Also, the `COMPILE_FLAGS` property is *deprecated*, and you should use `COMPILE_OPTIONS` instead.

Comment: @squareskittles Yes that makes sense. The question you linked answer my question in a way. What should I do with my question? Do I have a way to close it as there is already an answer in the one you linked?

Comment: It looks like it has been marked as a duplicate, so you may delete it yourself if you want, or just leave it up. There's a chance it gets deleted by site moderators in the future, but some duplicate questions are useful to keep on the site, as people search for answers to the same question in different ways. Some details about duplicates is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/506927).